# Windows 8 RTM Metro Apps Don't Work

Tags: windows, modern-ui, windows-store-app

I installed Windows 8 RTM into my PC. Everything is great. No BSODs, Halo: Combat Evolved is working seamlessly and other stuff but whenever I click on a Mondern UI app in the Start Screen, it opens up as usual but after a few moments of waiting, no text or images that usually appear in a Metro app shows up and the screen turns black. Then, a little later, a cursor appeared and I can move the cursor. But a few moments later, the screen turns black and suddenly I see that my PC just suddenly restarted amd rebooted again. So, fellow Windows 8 users or experts or etc., please help fix the problem. The problem is really annoying and disappointing. Thanks you in advance. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks. :D

PC Specs:
Processor: Intel Atom
RAM: 1.66 GB

Comment: What's your screen resolution set to?

Comment: I have set my screen resolution to 1024 by 768.